# The error shows the following: Field 'signoutUser' doesn't accept argument 'input'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

[Field 'signoutUser' doesn't accept argument 'input']

Here is the error I am getting
[image: 1]

I tried to code for logout mutation using Graphql on Ruby on Rails. However, it shows an error shown above. Try to click the link above to see the error. How can I solve the error of logout mutation?

Here is my code for 
app/graphql/mutations/sign_out_user.rb:

```
module Mutations
  class SignOutUser < BaseMutation
    null true 
    field :user, Types::UserType, null: false

    field :token, String, null: false

    argument :email, String, required: false

    def resolve(email:)
      user = User.find_by email: email[:email]
      return user.logout
      token = token.destroy!
      { user: user, token: token }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could you add more information about your problem, your question has more code then information.

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience. I am a beginner of Stack Overflow. That is why my information is somewhat unclear.

Comment: However, I am doing my own best to ask questions related to this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! We all create an account to ask a first question. I'll give you an up vote. At score 50 you'll can vote and will be one of us.

Comment: What I see is that you have unreachable code after return statement. Remove this line : `return user.logout`

Answer (score 0):

this one works

```
module Mutations
class SignOutUser < BaseMutation
  null true 

  argument :token, String, required: true

  field :token, String, null: false
  field :message, String, null: false


  def resolve(token:)
    user = User.find_by(session_token: token)
    if user
    user.session_token = "" 
    user.save!
    {
        token: user.session_token,
        message: "signout success!"
    }
    else
        context.add_error(GraphQL::ExecutionError.new("Invalid token", extensions: { "code" => "INVALID_TOKEN" }))
    end
  end
end
end
```